# Will the boot-degraded flag remain after upgrading to 14.04?

Tags: boot, upgrade, raid

I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04 and have a RAID setup with the boot-degraded option.  If I upgrade to 14.04 will the boot-degraded option remain?  I manage this server remotely and would hate to perform this upgrade only to have to take a road trip afterward to set the boot-degraded flag myself.

Answer (score 2):

The BOOT_DEGRADED variable is not used or supported in Ubuntu 14.04 or any other system with mdadm-3.2.5-5ubuntu3 or later (see change ["Drop degraded array questions, since the degraded check results in false negatives "](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdadm/+bug/1279741/comments/1)). The system should always boot even on a degraded array.

But - I read about various problems with it - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdadm/+bug/1341312.

Answer (score 1):

Just confirming that the BOOT_DEGRADED option is still supported in 14.04, and is still required if you want your server to boot automatically when a disk fails.

Source: anecdotal evidence. Just had a disk fail, and the server would drop to a initramfs shell, where I had to manually --force assemble the array.

Executing

```
echo 'BOOT_DEGRADED=true' > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/mdadm && update-initramfs -k all -u
```

as root and rebooting (to verify) did result in Ubuntu booting all the way, even with the still-degraded array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no harm in re-setting the boot degraded flag after update, just to be sure, but it is unlikely to be deleted.

```
echo 'BOOT_DEGRADED=true' > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/mdadm && update-initramfs -k all -u
```

The answer posted by "undefine" is incorrect (except in that he partially retracted it), and the one posted by "Stefan" correct, at least as is true of 16.04.